# findAndModify fails with error: "Cannot update 'field1' and 'field1' at the same time

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I'm trying to build MongoDB Java findAndModify query.

The main purpose is that I would like to set **_id** in insert query by myself.

Here is my code:

```
BasicDBObject findFilter = new BasicDBObject("type", "group")
//
BasicDBObject dialogInsertObject = new BasicDBObject("name", "my group").append("_id", new ObjectId());
//
BasicDBObject dialogUpdateObject = new BasicDBObject("name", "my group");
//
BasicDBObject upsertMap = new BasicDBObject();
upsertMap.append("$setOnInsert", dialogInsertObject);
upsertMap.append("$set", dialogUpdateObject);


DBObject dialogObject = dialogCollection.findAndModify(findFilter, 
   new BasicDBObject("_id", "1"), null, false, upsertMap, true, true);
```

And I get an error:

```
com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" : "localhost:27017" , 
  "errmsg" : "exception: Cannot update 'name' and 'name' at the same time" , 
  "code" : 16836 , "ok" : 0.0}
```

Can somebody help please

Comment: Pretty much as the error says. You cannot set both the same things within `$setOnInsert` and `$set` at the same time. Also your `dialogInsertObject` values are overwriting.

Comment: sorry, updated dialogInsertObject. Why I can't use $set and $setOnInsert in single query?

Comment: @NeilLunn as documentation says, $setOnInsert is for insert, but $set is for update operation. What's wrong?

Comment: @NeilLunn read http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/  Upsert Results in an Update

Comment: Not the person you should be saying "read the docs to" as I am sure I know them a lot better than most. You can use both terms the problem is you are using the same "field" in both. Calm down and read what I said in the first place if not this.

Comment: @NeilLunn common man, you didn't provide much info in your 1st comment. Would you like to say that $set operator also works for insert operation?

Comment: This reallt should have been clear but now you have an answer to really make it clear what you are trying to do

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The essential problem here is this:

```js
db.collection.update(
   { "type": "group" },
   { 
      "$set": { "mygroup": "value" }
      "$setOnInsert" { "mygroup": "value" }
   }
)
```

Which is basically what you are trying to do.

You cannot address the **same** field in a **`$set`** operation as a **`$setOnInsert`** operation.

There is a general problem in the logic that causes the error you are experiencing.

Comment: so, I should include _id only to $setOnInsert and this a right  solution. Thanks

Comment: @IgorKhomenko The bottom line is that if you reference the **same** thing in both statements you are causing a conflict when something is actually inserted. But I hope you see that now.

Comment: This bit me as well, and the first comment is wrong. You should only specify it in the $set block, since $set is applied even when it's inserting a new document. They are not mutually exclusive (being familiar with MySQL ON DUPLICATE KEY syntax confused me).