# Mongodb - duplicate fields in $set and $setOnInsert

Tags: mongodb, upsert

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23992723/findandmodify-fails-with-error-cannot-update-field1-and-field1-at-the-same/23994425#23994425) post, the accepted answer explains that you cannot have the same fields under `$set` and `$setOnInsert` in an upsert operation.

Can someone explain why this is?  It seems like the `$setOnInsert` shouldn't conflict with `$set`, since the former is used when a document is inserted, and the latter is used when the document is updated.

Comment: Honestly, I don't have an explanation for why this is the case now; I'd like to see this implemented as well. There is an enhancement request, [SERVER-10711](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-10711), to allow `$set` and `$setOnInsert` to work in the same update on the same field. You can comment, watch, and upvote that issue to raise its priority.

Comment: thank you for pointing this out @wdberkeley.  do you know if there's a workaround to this without needing two queries?

Answer (score 6):

I faced this problem. If someone is looking for a solution, you need to understand how the $set and $setOnInsert mechanism works
$set refreshes if found (**ignoring $setOnInsert**)
$setOnInsert inserts a new record (**and then executes $set**)
I did not know this and thought that only one operator would work. This way I was able to get rid of duplicate fields

Comment: Hmmm! That's why they don't allow the same field in both at the same time. That makes sense (for the way it works). Although I still think they should support something to allow setting a different value on insert, as [the comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27552352/mongodb-duplicate-fields-in-set-and-setoninsert/33844252?noredirect=1#comment74261104_33844252)

Answer (score 1):

**$set** operator is used on **upsert** too. So it's nonsense to refer same fields both on **$set** and **$setOnInsert**.

Just try this on an empty collection:

```
db.items.remove();
db.items.update({},{$set:{a:1},$setOnInsert:{b:2}},{upsert:1})
db.items.find({});
```

Comment: It's not "nonsense". For example, I need a field to be `true` if the document was just inserted, and to be `false` if it was just updated. If same field exists in both `$set`(as `false`) and `$setOnInsert`(as `true`), and the document is inserted, the field in `$setOnInsert` should take precedence even though it exists as well in the `$set` section.

Comment: @maganap i wanna do exactly that. is there a way ?

Comment: @GrayHat It's been a long time since I last worked with MongoDB, so I really couldn't tell. Sorry I can't help here.