# $inc vs. $setOnInsert in MongoCollection.findOneAndUpdate()

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to implement a `'server-side counter-versioned'` item in mongodb and trying to do following /* *using Java API* */

```
Document dbDoc = dbCollection.findOneAndUpdate(
        new Document("_id", "meta"), 
        new Document("$inc", new Document("version", 1))
             .append("$setOnInsert", new Document("version", 0)),
        new FindOneAndUpdateOptions().upsert(true)
                                     .returnDocument(ReturnDocument.AFTER));
```

Assumed logic is simple: if there is no record in database - start counting from zero (and with a whole fresh new object), otherwise - increment counter.

Code sample fails with: `'Cannot update 'version' and 'version' at the same time'`

My assumption is that in 'upsert' mode mongo should only use "$setOnInsert" when no matching item is found - but it works in some other way.

Is it possible to implement such operation in **one atomic** mongoDB call?

---

PS: [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-behavior) regarding findOneAndUpdate() and upsert() is fuzzy - at least I cannot get why this error arizes from their description.

Also there is similar question here - [findAndModify fails with error: "Cannot update 'field1' and 'field1' at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23992723/findandmodify-fails-with-error-cannot-update-field1-and-field1-at-the-same) - accepted, but again with no clear reasoning.

Comment: I'd like to add this example, when you have a nested object with values: {_id: 1, hours: { 0:0, 1:0, 2:0 }} and you want to add and increase an hour if the document doesn't exists or just add to an hour if it does. Actually this is not possible and it isn't against any logic.

Answer (score 4):

You can just remove the update operator of `$setOnInsert` as this will be set to the value specified in the `$inc` operator if the document does not exist

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/update/inc/#behavior

> If the field does not exist, $inc creates the field and sets the field to the specified value.

Example from the mongo shell:

```
> db.dropDatabase()
{ "ok" : 1 }
> db.test.findOneAndUpdate({_id: "meta"}, { $inc: { version: 1} }, {upsert: true, returnNewDocument: true})
{ "_id" : "meta", "version" : 1 }
> db.test.findOneAndUpdate({_id: "meta"}, { $inc: { version: 1} }, {upsert: true, returnNewDocument: true})
{ "_id" : "meta", "version" : 2 }
> db.test.findOneAndUpdate({_id: "meta"}, { $inc: { version: 1} }, {upsert: true, returnNewDocument: true})
{ "_id" : "meta", "version" : 3 }
> db.test.findOneAndUpdate({_id: "meta"}, { $inc: { version: 1} }, {upsert: true, returnNewDocument: true})
{ "_id" : "meta", "version" : 4 }
> db.test.findOneAndUpdate({_id: "meta"}, { $inc: { version: 1} }, {upsert: true, returnNewDocument: true})
{ "_id" : "meta", "version" : 5 }
```

If you need to set a given version on the first initial insert, then mongodb does not support any operators to support this atomically, however the follow would be safe and is a common workaround:

```
> db.dropDatabase()
{ "dropped" : "test", "ok" : 1 }
> function updateMeta(){
...   function update(){
...     return db.test.findOneAndUpdate({_id: "meta"}, { $inc: { version: 1} }, {returnNewDocument: true});
...   }
...
...   var result = update();
...
...   if(result === null){
...     db.test.insert({_id: "meta", version: -10});
...     result = update();
...   }
...
...   return result;
... }
>
> updateMeta()
{ "_id" : "meta", "version" : -9 }
> updateMeta()
{ "_id" : "meta", "version" : -8 }
> updateMeta()
{ "_id" : "meta", "version" : -7 }
> updateMeta()
{ "_id" : "meta", "version" : -6 }
> updateMeta()
{ "_id" : "meta", "version" : -5 }
>
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I need - i'd like to start with '0' (zero) (or may be some other number) as initial counter value.

Comment: That variation is not **one atomic mongoDB call**, it means parallel execution of the same function from many different clients will cause unpredictable results.

Comment: @XtraCoder we take advantage of atomic operations in the above. We try to update the document first, If that fails then we try to ensure that that a document is added then update the new document. The insert could happen multiple times but only one would succeed and return a `{ "nInserted" : 1 }` then all the consequent updates will happen atomically. This is more of a workaround as to answer you question it isn't possible to do this in one atomic action.

Comment: In your specific code sample 10 different clients can simultaneously enter `update()`, all of them will receive `null` as the result and then all of them will perform 10 `insert` operations, some will fail because of duplicates, thus causing not very predictable results. This is not what is called **atomic**.

Comment: Insert won't fail it will just return a result of inserted=0, the whole function is predictable as it still won't get out of sync even if concurrent clients hit the insert method as it will only insert one document. unless you have really slow machines or network the probability of concurrent hits to the update before an insert will be low. but as I said the method above is safe with concurrency.

Comment: double-attempt to `db.test.insert({_id: "meta", version: -10});` results in `E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.t index: _id_ dup key: { : "meta" }` - this is what will happen for multiple clients going parallel into `if(result === null){ ... }` ... ok, actually changing `insert` to `upsert` will do this safely, however this does not look to be a 'good' way.

Comment: The *javascript* and *C#* driver both don't throw an exception but just return a result, then you can check that result if required. not sure about the *Java* driver, but these are just expected return values. As long as your application deals with them correctly you're sound.

Comment: Don't use an upsert, because that will set the initial value to -10 multiple times, possibly overwriting intermediate $inc's, thus losing their results. Just catch and dismiss the error instead.